# Could anyone explain in python why the setter method in the sub-class is called when calling super().__init__()

Tags: python

Could someone give me some insight why the sub class setter `def voltage(self, voltage)` is called when calling `super().__init__()`?

```
class Resistor():
  def __init__(self):
    self.voltage = 0

class VoltageResister(Resistor):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  @property
  def voltage(self):
    return self._voltage
  
  @voltage.setter
  def voltage(self, voltage):
    print('voltage setter called')
    self._voltage = voltage

a = VoltageResister()

# wonder why it prints "voltage setter called"?
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are calling the `__init__` method of `Resistor` which explicitly sets `self.voltage`, triggering the setter you have defined.

Comment: Why would you expect the setter for voltage *not* to be called?

Comment: @jfaccioni Why the superclass portion needs to call sub-class setter method? Can't it just create an attribute for itself called "voltage"? So that at the end of the initialization, "a" contains an attribute called "voltage" because no one called the subclass setter method yet?

Comment: Because classes always look into their own namespace before looking at the parent's namespace. If that wasn't the case, `VoltageResister` wouldn't be able to overwrite `voltage.setter` if `Resistor` had one defined as well. Calling the parent's `Resistor.__init__` does not mean that all methods/properties called inside it will be the parent's methods/properties; the child's methods/properties are used instead if they are available.

Comment: Thanks @jfaccioni. I understand after the object is constructed, that is the case. I am thinking about in the __init__() method even I specifically call super(), it still runs sub-class methods. What if I just want to run base class version of a overrided method?

Comment: That's simply not how it works. Methods are just functions. `self` is a `VoltageResistor` object, which defines a `property` for `voltage`, hence, `self.voltage = 0` invokes that property. It's as simple as that

Comment: At that point you'd have to either call the parent method directly (`super().myparentmethod`) or simply not implement it in the child class. It's not the best, but naming the child method the same as the parent method, and then trying call the parent method kinda defeats the purpose of inheritance. And I think it gets messier when you're dealing with properties/attributes rather than actual methods, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: The object has already been constructed; `__init__()` is an initializer, NOT a constructor.  The same rules apply then as at any other time.  But if you want the base class version of a method only, you can explicitly invoke it via `super().method()`...

Comment: @Han the object is already constructed by the time you are in `__init__`, again, that's what gets passed to `self`. In any case, how would you even expect this to work? How would you expect an object with an instance attribute `.voltage` and a property with the same name to behave? Notice, you can do this and it will always invoke the descriptor anyway.... so what's the point?

Comment: Thanks guys for all the useful information, I think I get it now. @juanpa.arrivillaga, I haven't got into those complicated scenarios to think through for your first 2 questions, but I believe I can access the parent's `.voltage` attribute by calling super().voltage to avoid the descriptor if in my base class `__init__` method I use `super().voltage` instead of `self.voltage'.